# login page going into loop in 14.04

Tags: login, login-screen

I am only able to login into guest account.
I tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> , and got the terminal login.
But its not accepting my credentials, the correct one. 
I am not able to `sudo` , Please suggest me something.